# Доработка сайта 1с-Битрикс

Tags: вёрстка, битрикс

Существует уже готовый сайт на 1с-Битрикс, к которому у меня есть админка. Также у меня есть свёрстанный компонент (слайдер) на чистом html/css/js.
Как мне решить задачу создания нового раздела на готовом сайте с моей вёрсткой? Не совсем понимаю, как перенести файлы в cms

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=34&INDEX=Y